# How can I get a list of files in a git commit?

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have committed a few files on `master` and also merged some of the local branches with `master` branch. How can I get the list of committed files on the `master` branch?

Comment: You said you already commited them, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: if we staged some files, we can see the files with git status. How can  I see the committed files? I need the command like git status for listing the committed files.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, maybe `git ls-files` is what you need.

Comment: I want to know what all are the files I committed in the branch.

Comment: gitk will show all the commits and information of all the files committed wrt that commit. You can also do git log

Comment: @pala I think the OP is looking for a purely CLI solution.

Comment: @Jubobs: Sorry, none helped me. I could not found the list of committed files in my branch. I will explain the scenario once again. 1 I have staged files using git add. and committed those staged files using git commit -m 'comment'. My need is to get the list of committed files using any command.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the list of committed files on the `master` branch?

`git ls-tree` lists the contents of a tree object. By default, it lists the permission, type, hash, and associated filename of each object referenced in the tree object, but you can tell it to print only the filename by using the `--name-only` option.

```
git ls-tree --name-only master
```

**Edit** (thanks Alex): you also probably want to use the `-r` flag to recurse into subtrees (i.e. the tree objects "nested" inside the top tree object of your commit).

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only master
```

Comment: most likely you want to add `-r` for recursive

Answer (score 1):

I usually use

```
git ls-files
```

In the given plain form, it simply prints out the files committed in the current branch.
To view files of a different branch, add the [`--with-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) parameter:

```
git ls-files --with-tree=master
```

lists all files of the `master` branch.

[The docs of `git ls-files`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) provide more fine tuning possibilities.